# Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with three buttons. When Ok button is clicked i wrote the below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Call calculateCost
End Sub
```

and the sub method i wrote in the Sheet1 is:

```
Public Sub calculateCost()
    Dim kilo As String
    kilo = Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox "value" & kilo
End Sub
```

When im running the code im getting the error. Sub or function not defined near call calculateCost. Why is this happening? How to resolve this. Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your calculatedCost procedure to a standard module (Insert - Module in the VBE).  Procedures in a class module, including a sheet class module, can't be called like that.  You can call it from a sheet's class module in other ways, but I don't see anything in your procedure that requires it be in the sheet's module, so it probably belongs in a standard module.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But im now getting a runtime error while storing the textbox value into variable: object doesn't support this method or variable. Can you help me with this

Comment: @Pramod Instead of `TextBox.Text` try using `TextBox.Value`